# DRF serializer's BooleanField returns null for empty ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I want to add boolean fields `has_video` and `has_gallery` to my serializer.

Their values should be `true` if the ForeignKey fields of MyModel (video, gallery) have values, otherwise these values should be set to `false`.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(
        to='videos.Video',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(
        to='galleries.Gallery',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    has_video = serializers.BooleanField(source='video', default=False)
    has_gallery = serializers.BooleanField(source='gallery', default=False)
```

The problem occurs when the video or gallery value of MyModel object is null. I expect the returned values to be false but it is null.

```
        "has_video": null,
        "has_gallery": null,
```

I try to set `allow_null` parameters to `false` but the result is the same (the values are still `null`).

```
has_video = serializers.BooleanField(source='video', default=False, allow_null=False)
has_gallery = serializers.BooleanField(source='gallery', default=False, allow_null=False)
```

When the video or gallery is not null, the serializer's fields return true as I expect. The problem is just about null/false values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the approach I have followed in one of my project.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    has_video = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_has_video', read_only=True)
    has_gallery = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_has_gallery', read_only=True)
    # ... Your other fields 
    class Meta:
        model = "Your model name"
        fields = ("your model fields",
                  ,"has_video", "has_gallery") # include the above two fields
        
    def get_has_video(self, obj):
        # now your object should be having videos then you want True so do this like this
        return True if obj.video else False
    
    def get_has_gallery(self, obj):
        # now your object should be having galleries then you want True so do this like this
        return True if obj.gallery else False
```

Comment: instead of `True if obj.video else False` python function `bool` might be use. for example; `bool(obj.video)` returns `True` if `obj` have `video` otherwise returns `False`.

Comment: No this may not be useful because it will fetch all the results of obj.video then it will check, firstly i thought of this way only. In the docs its stated `simply using bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned`. The much better approach will be to `return obj.video.exists()`

Comment: For optimization in #views.py , OP can override `get_queryset()` and in that you can use `MyModel.objects.all().select_related('video', 'gallery')` This will result in much optimized query and fast results.

Comment: I wondered if I can still use the `serializers.BooleanField` for this case but it looks like I should really use `serializers.SerializerMethodField` instead. Thank you for your answer.